# Trying to match a REST parameter argument in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

the string to match is

```
/t5/Work-Planning-Scheduling-Ideas/steeples-Throneberry/idi-p/711/jump-to/first-unread-message
```

this is my javascript regex expression `(\/[0-9]+)(?!idi-p)` . I want to get the `711` out of that url

Comment: is the values around `711` are always consistent ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a negative lookahead, you could first match the `/idi-p/` part of the path and use the capturing group `(\d+)` to match 1+ digits.

```
\/idi-p\/(\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\/idi-p\/` Match `/idi-p/`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aLeicx/1)

```js
const regex = /\/idi-p\/(\d+)/;
const str = `/t5/Work-Planning-Scheduling-Ideas/steeples-Throneberry/idi-p/711/jump-to/first-unread-message`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1])
```